# Why mp3 file cannot be autoplayed in Qualtrics?

Tags: qualtrics

I inserted an mp3 file into Qualtrics from my library following the instruction here: https://www.qualtrics.com/support/survey-platform/survey-module/editing-questions/rich-content-editor/insert-media/

I would have several pages and one mp3 per page, so I tried to make the mp3 file automatically played, and people don't need to click "play" on every page. I followed the instruction here: https://www.kent.ac.uk/psychology/downloads/Qualtrics-MP3-FAQ.pdf

As you can see in the image attached, I have set "autostart = true", however, when I check in the preview mode, the mp3 file is still not automatically played.

Do you have any ideas about which step could go wrong? Or is there any alternative way to make the mp3 file autoplayed in Qualtrics? Thanks in advance!